# Upload files using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this code to be able to upload a file that its <=10 MB in a folder on my server and also send its name to the database so that later I'll be able to generate the link to access that file.

My problem is that if the `$fileSize` its > 10MB it won't execute the `move_uploaded_file` but it will execute the query to the database and it will `INSERT` an entry with the file name (so i will have records to in-existing files). I think this happens because the `$errMSG` comes empty for that condition.

Can you have a look?  Thank You!

```
require_once ('db.php');

if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)) {

    $userFile = $_FILES['cv']['name'];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['cv']['size'];

    if (empty($userFile)) {
       echo  $errMSG = "Please Select File.";
    } else {
        $upload_dir = './files/'; // upload directory

        $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($userFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get file extension

        // valid image extensions
        $valid_extensions = array('doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'ppt','pptx','txt','jpeg','jpg','png'); // valid extensions

        // rename uploading image
        $userFileName = rand(1000, 1000000) . "." . $fileExt;

        // allow valid image file formats
        if (in_array($fileExt, $valid_extensions,$fileSize <= 10000000) ){
            // Check file size '10MB
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir . $userFileName);
        } else {
              echo $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large or its not JPG JPEG PNG PDF DOC DOX TXT.";
        }
    }
}
if(!isset($errMSG)) {
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO files (filename) VALUES(:filename)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':filename',$userFileName);
    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
        header("refresh:5;index.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are uploading more than one file ?

Comment: The 3rd parameter in `in_array()` is for strict comparison (including the variable type), it is not related in any way to file sizes or limits.

Comment: Just one file @odai

Comment: @jeroen Used this if (in_array($fileExt, $valid_extensions) && $fileSize <= 10000000)    The file its still kept not sent to the server but it executes the INSERT query

Comment: add a variable after {if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST))} with a defualt value false and change it to true after $errMSG and make the condition using it

Comment: Try uploading a small(er) file. If it works, then the file you're trying to upload which is larger than what you're trying to avoid getting, is larger than what your system will allow you to upload. If that's the case, you will need to increase the max upload size setting. Check for error number `$_FILES['cv']['error']`. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- That its not the case. I try to upload a small file...It works. If I upload a file that its too big it executes the query when it should`t

Comment: [cv] => Array
        (
            [name] => oversize_pdf_test_0.pdf
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )

) Looks like if the file its bigger then 10 MB it evals it with 0 and it will pass the condition

Comment: Oh, so "that's" what the *real* question is about. Well then, just put your query inside where you're using `move_uploaded_file...` then. I think it's just a logic thing here and your conditionals are a bit off. You could also (try) put(ting) the closing brace for `if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)) {` at the end of the one for `if(!isset($errMSG)) {`. Maybe even a few `exit`'s here and there to stop execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd parameter for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is for strict comparison (including the variable type), it is not related in any way to file sizes or limits.

So instead of this:

```
if (in_array($fileExt, $valid_extensions,$fileSize <= 10000000) ){
```

You probably want something like this:

```
if (in_array($fileExt, $valid_extensions) && $fileSize <= 10000000) {
```

**Edit:** Based on the comments below the question, your upload has failed: `[error] => 2`. That should be `0` / `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` for a successful upload.

Instead of checking for a non-empty name, you should check for a successful upload instead:

```
if ($_FILES['cv']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // the upload has failed
} else {
    ...
```

Comment: I did that at first and it failed on me. Lets try again

Comment: I did this again and It runs my query for INSERT and also the validation doesn't echo the err message   echo $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large ..... I`ve tried to upload an 101 MB pdf..